# Android DialogFragment Dismissal

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I've looked at several of the questions pertaining to handling an orientation change in a DialogFragment, and the common theme seems to be that the askers aren't getting any answers, at none that I understand...

So, I'd like to take a different approach...  Is there a way I can programmatically dismiss the dialog...  Looking at my LogCat, I can see that if the dialogfragment is active, and the screen orientation is changed, then my Activity restarts.

Along the way, the DialogFragment is also restarted, but this happens after onCreate and before onResume (as close as I can tell).  It's fairly simple for me to detect this in my dialog, and what I'd like to do is abort the dialog view creation in this case.  What I've tried so far is like this:

```
    if (normal_conditions_detected)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate (R.layout.dialog_layout, container, false);
        final Dialog d = getDialog();
        d.setTitle (R.string.sensor_config);

        ... more stuff
        return v
    }
    else
    {
        getDialog().cancel();
        return null;
    }
```

This does avoid the null pointer nonsense I was getting, but now I get what I can only describe as an empty dialog, even with the cancel() command in there.  Is there a way I can get my dialogFragment code to refuse to create the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you rotate your device, activity executes

```
onSaveInstanceState
```

method and save the current state which means it saves your fragment state as well, after recreation it executes

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

method again, savedInstanceState holds your old data, in here you can make something like

```
if (savedInstanceState == null){
   YourDialogFragment f = new YourDialogFragment()
   f.show // etc
}
```

Only once your fragment will be created, instead of putting a control inside fragment, you can control it by the activity

Comment: I think this will throw NullPointerException, since the DialogFragment will be restored after screen rotation because it have its own life cycle (it is a guess), wouldn't be better dismiss the dialog if the savedInstanceState isn't null?

Comment: I did a brief experiment with the Bundle passed to onCreate. When I first start up the Activity, the Bundle is null, and when I rotate the screen the Bundle is definitely not null.  I guess what I would need to figure out is how to find the DialogFragment information in the bundle and remove it??  Or perhaps detect it and remove it, then start the DialogFragment at better point in the lifecycle??